# Вероятность выпадения минимум 2 орлов подряд из 4 попыток

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей

Как правильно считать вероятности?

Подбрасываем монету, например, какова вероятность выпадения 2х орлов подряд из 4 попыток?

Когда задаешь подобный вопрос, то специалисты в комбинаторике, почему, начинают прикидывать, что всего успешных комбинаций 3: выпадение на позициях 1-2 2-3 3-4.... `оорр роор рроо`

Вроде как логично, но... почему они не учитывают, что при выпадении комбинация типа `ооро` тоже входит в множество, ибо и в этом случае мы достигли результата? А ведь учитывая все варианты расстановки, мы получим не 3 варианта, а 8!

Что не так в логике? Или что-то не так в постановке задачи?

Как получить эти 8 вариантов используя формулу?

Кроме `оорр роор рроо` подпадают под условие и варианты типа `ооро ороо оооо` и т.д.

подскажите логику и формулу расчета любого минимального количества подряд орла (k) из n попыток

Comment: Стоп-стоп! Сформулируйте задачу точно. Просто два орла подряд, или всего 2 орла, и оба подряд? Первое решение - если известно, что выпадает ровно 2 орла, то какова вероятность, что они выпадут подряд. Второе - ваше - просто какова вероятность получить при четырех бросках 2 орла подряд. И это - разные задачи... Какую именно задачу вы хотите решить?

Comment: 4 раза подбросили минимум 2 подряд орла

Comment: Общей формулы для минимум 2 орлов подряд из n попыток достаточно? Или надо максимально общее для минимум k орлов из n попыток?

Comment: вроде любого варианта достаточно для примера

Comment: @moonfox для примера да, но вы в комментариях указали "подбросили 134 раза какова вероятность выпадения орла минимум 5 раз", т.е. произвольные числа?

Comment: а разве формула не универсальная? как-то нахождение сочетаний из n по m?
тогда общую для минимум k

Comment: @moonfox ну я пока смог придумать только вариант с 2 и n, этот вариант на k и n не обобщается, на первый взгляд. Понятно, что когда есть вариант для k и n, он будет работать и для 2 и n :)

Comment: И зачем тут комбинаторика??? В теории вероятности есть хорошая тема "Условная вероятность". Советую ознакомится. И жить станет легче)

Comment: посмотрите на формулы комбинаторики
ахахаха, хороший у вас комент

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложу вариант решения задачи "вероятность выпадения минимум `2` орлов подряд из `n` попыток".

Будем обозначать орла и решку `o` и `p`, последовательность выпадений орла и решки за `n` попыток словом длины `n` (например, `opoop` — подходящее слово длины 5).

Рассмотрим:

- `a_n` — количество слов длины `n`, в которых **нет** `2` подряд орлов **И** которые оканчиваются на `o` (для `n = 3` имеем `a_n = 2`: `opo`, `ppo`)
- `b_n` — количество слов длины `n`, в которых **нет** `2` подряд орлов **И** которые оканчиваются на `p` (для `n = 3` имеем `b_n = 3`: `opp`, `pop`, `ppp`)

Тогда заметим:

1. `a_n+1 = b_n`, потому что получить количество слов длины `n+1`, в которых **нет** `2` подряд орлов **И** которые оканчиваются на `o`, можно только добавлением `o` к словам длины `n`. Добавить `o`, не получив `2` подряд `o`, можно только к словам, оканчивающимся на `p`
2. `b_n+1 = a_n + b_n`, потому что получить количество слов длины `n+1`, в которых **нет** `2` подряд орлов **И** которые оканчиваются на `p`, можно только добавлением `p` к словам длины `n`. Добавить `p`, не получив `2` подряд `o`, можно как к оканчивающимся на `o` словам, так и к оканчивающимся на `p` словам

Рассмотрим сумму:

`a_n + b_n = <используем 1> = b_n-1 + b_n = <используем 2> = b_n-1 + a_n-1 + b_n-1 = <ещё раз используем 2> = (a_n-2 + b_n-2) + (a_n-1 + b_n-1)`

Внезапно, получили, что последовательность сумм является последовательностью Фибоначчи. Рассмотрев базовые случаи (`F_1` и `F_2`), по индукции получаем, что `a_n + b_n = F_n+2`.

Тогда слова длины `n`, содержащие минимум `2` орла, находятся как все возможные слова (их `2^n`) минус слова, в которых нет `2` подряд `o` (`a_n + b_n = F_n+2`).

Итоговая вероятность: `(2^n - F_n+2) / 2^n`.

Аналитически: `(2^n - round(phi^n / sqrt(5)) / 2^n`, где `phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2`

Примеры:

- для `n = 4` получаем: `(16 - 8) / 16 = 0.5`
- для `n = 5` получаем: `(32 - 13) / 32 = 0.59375`

Для `k` орлов можно использовать [последовательности Фибоначчи `k`-ого порядка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0), как указал участник [@MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo) в [своём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1174829/398802). На Википедии как раз сказано, что *"Последователь количеств строк из 0 и 1 длины m, содержащих не более n последовательных нулей, также является последовательностью Фибоначчи порядка n."* и приводятся аналитические формулы для подсчёта членов таких последовательностей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Забавно, что именно это можно решать, как блондинка из анекдота - "1/2, или получим, или нет!" :) А если всерьез...

Решаем вашу задачу - 2 орла подряд из 4 выпадений. Проще всего просто расписать все варианты - их всего 16 - и посчитать:

```
oooo  ooop  oopo  oopp
opoo  opop  oppo  oppp
pooo  poop  popo  popp
ppoo  ppop  pppo  pppp
```

Как видите, нужных вариантов - 8. Итого - вероятность получить 2 орла подряд - 1/2.

Так просто и понятно, или вы хотите какое-то иное решение?...

**Update**

"По формуле"...

Для данного случая рассматриваем 2 орла начиная с 1, 2 и 3 выпадения. Вероятность такого выпадения - 1/4.

Для первого выпадения вероятность - 1/4.
Для второго выпадения вероятность 1/4, умноженная на вероятность, что первое выпадение решка (1/2) = `1/4*1/2 = 1/8`.
Для третьего выпадения вероятность 1/4, умноженная на вероятность, что второе выпадение решка (1/2) = `1/4*1/2 = 1/8`.
Итого общая вероятность = `1/4+1/8+1/8 = 1/2`.

Так сойдет?

Comment: можно я процитирую вопрос? "как получить эти 8 вариантов используя формулу???"

Comment: @Kromster **Какую именно** формулу?

Comment: та да, именно так я и расписал, а если я усложню задачу 
подбросили 134 раза какова вероятность выпадения орла минимум 5 раз подряд
предлагаете расписать?

Comment: Было бы правильнее рассказать какая будет математическая формула, применимая для других аналогичных случаев, например, для 8 орлов подряд из 32 бросков. Как в общем случае посчитать, то что требуется топикстартеру.

Comment: @Kromster Тут надо поразбираться... Сейчас нет времени, так что если кто-то даст более точный ответ - я свой удалю, если нет - то постараюсь со временем дополнить свой...

Comment: @Kromster Набросал рассуждения - устраивает?

Comment: а попробуйте минимум 3 из 4, что у вас выходит?

Comment: Аналогично. Вероятность первых трех орлов - 1/8, вероятность вторых трех при условии, что первые 3 - не орлы - 1/8*1/2, итого в сумме 3/16.

Comment: интересный вариант и как-то оч просто выходит

Answer (score 2):

От противного: посчитаем, сколько вариантов длиной N **не содержат** двух орлов подряд.

Назовём эту функцию `F(N)`

Количество вариантов с последней решкой равно `F(N-1)` (решку можно добавить к любому хорошему варианту меньшей длины)

Количество вариантов с последним орлом равно `F(N-2)`, т.к. их  можно получить, только добавив `ро` к варианту с длиной, меньшей на 2.

Итого получается

```
F(N) = F(N-1) + F(N-2)
```

т.е. числа Фибоначчи. А искомый ответ для количества вариантов, содержащих два орла подряд хотя бы один раз:

```
O(N) =  2^N - Fib(N)

N   O(N)
1   0
2   1
3   3
4   8
5   19
```

Для большего количества k орлов подобная (но более сложная) логика приведёт к использованию последовательностей Фибоначчи порядка k.

Например, для трёх орлов будет последовательность "трибоначчи"

```
1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24,
```

Например, для n=5 будет 32-24=8 вариантов с минимум тремя орлами, для n=4: 16-13=3 варианта

Для n=6,k=4 с использованием "тетраначчи"  64-56=8 вариантов